# How can I update a custom view (by calling invalidate()) every X seconds? (This is for a BrickBreaker game)

Tags: android

I am trying to write a BrickBreaker game for Android, and I want to be able to update my BrickBreakerView (which contains the ball, paddle, etc.) every X seconds. Currently, the UI is only updated when the user touches the screen.

Between the updates, I will be changing data of the paddle, bricks, and balls, and when the onDraw() method is called (UI updates), I want to update the view with the data.

Currently, I only have a paddle, and when the user touches the screen and moves their finger, the position of the paddle updates, and invalidate() is called. Here is my code:

```
 private Paddle paddle;
private int fingerAdjustor = 75;

public BrickBreakerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    setOnTouchListener(this);
    setOnClickListener(null);
    paddle = new Paddle(100, 675, 150,25);
    invalidate();
}
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        int x = (int) event.getX();
        paddle.setXPosition(x);
        invalidate();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawRect(paddle.getX()-fingerAdjustor, paddle.getY(), paddle.getX() + paddle.getPaddleWidth()-fingerAdjustor, paddle.getY() + paddle.getPaddleHeight(), paint);

}
```

Would this involve using a timer of some sort? If you could give me some examples or tell how I would implement this, I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your onDraw, when you've finished drawing everything and the position of your ball and bricks have changed, call invalidate() again to update the new positions.

Comment: Wouldn't that be inefficient? Considering the fact that the ball should get updated all the time, there must be a better(timed) way to do it. Calling invalidate would make it so android does a re-render cycle, kinda like infinite loop just controlled by the OS (Am I wrong?)  Is that what android suggests? (I'm not an android expert, just curious)

Comment: @DeusDeceit use surface view for these purposes. Plus no. You need to update the layout, so android has to go through that phase to update values.